# Returning a trained scikit learn (random forest) model from a function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am training a random forest model and have found that returning the trained model object from a function consistently results in different `.predict` behavior. Is this intended or not?

I think this is completely reproducible code. Input data is just 1000 rows of 6 columns of floats:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

def as_a_function():
    df = pd.to_csv() # read file
    lcscols = #just a list of 6/12 of the columns in the csv file that are used to build the model (ignore timestamp, etc)
    selcol = #y 'real' data

    train_df = df.sample(frac=testsize,random_state=42)
    test_df = df.drop(train_df.index)  #test/train split
        
    rfmodel, fitvals_mid = RF_model(train_df,test_df,selcol, lcscols)

    tempdf = df.copy(deep=True) # new copy, not totally necessary but helpful in edge cases
    tempdf.dropna(inplace=True)
    selcolname = selcol + '_cal'
    mid_cal = pd.DataFrame(data=rfmodel.predict(tempdf[lcscols]),index=tempdf.index,columns=[selcolname])
    #new df just made from a .predict call
    # note that input order of columns matters, needs to be identical to training order??

def RF_model(train_df, test_df, ycol, xcols):
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
    rfmodel = rf.fit(train_df[xcols], train_df[ycol])
    y_pred_test = rfmodel.predict(test_df[xcols])
    #missing code to test predicted values of testing set
    return rfmodel

#################################

def inline():
    df = pd.to_csv() # read file
    lcscols = #just a list of 6/12 of the columns in the csv file that are used to build the model (ignore timestamp, etc)
    refcol = #'true' data

    X = df[lcscols].values
    y = df[[refcol]].values
        
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
    ramp = rf.fit(x_train, y_train.flatten())
    y_pred_test = ramp.predict(x_test)
    #missing code to check prediction on test values
        
    tempdf = df.copy(deep=True)[lcscols]
    tempdf.dropna(axis=1,how='all',inplace=True)
    tempdf.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
    df_cal = pd.DataFrame(data=ramp.predict(tempdf),index=tempdf.index,columns=['name'])

    return df_cal
```

The problem is that `rfmodel.predict(tempdf[lcscols])` produces different output than `ramp.predict(tempdf)`.

I imagine that it's going to be somewhat different given that `pd.DataFrame.sample` is not going to be the exact same split as `test_train_split` but it's **r^2 value of 0.98** when .predict is called on the trained model in the **same function** as  compared to **r^2 = 0.5 when `.predict` is called on a returned model object**. That seems like way too different to be attributable to a different split method?

Comment: What is `newdf`?

Comment: oops, sorry, should just be 'df'.  Edited.  Perils of renaming variables for posting on SO

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a [dataset from `sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.datasets "Link to list sklearn datasets -->")? If so, then we could try it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using np.random.seed(42) before you call the method - Make sure you have numpy imported first. Every time the model predicts it uses random values, every time you run your code with that seed it uses different random values, however when you use np.random.seed(42), every time you run your code the model will use the same random values.

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue.  I'm actually running both of the 2 methods side by side and just copy/pasting the as_a_function code onto the bottom of the inline function (while changing the names) and it's still producing the same behaviour